# How to remove everything after some character and Hyphen in regex?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to get some data from Annotations:

```
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        kubernetes.io/change-cause:
                          Branch=master-9eb8251 Message=Revert "ON-1796 Re-write the cart GET for edit cart (#1256)" (#1284)

                          This reverts commit 27e600f83ecd98923713e2996d0aeea0da2df8fa. Author=Gautam Prajapati Timestamp=2019-07-29T16:26:32.622777
```

I want to get the result as (only branch name):

`master`

I am using the following command:

```
System.out.println(/*"branch:" +*/ result.getMetadata().getAnnotations().get("kubernetes.io/change-cause").replaceAll("Message=.*[^/]*$", "").replaceAll("Branch=", "").replaceAll("-[^-]+$", ""));
```

I get the errors because this is compatible only with Java not Groovy.

Comment: Maybe`.replaceFirst(/-[^-]*$/, "")`? What is your input? What is the rule to get your expected result? What is your expected result?

Comment: I have added the changes

Comment: You can easily extract the value with a *matching* approach, no need to remove anything. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57407922/3832970).

Comment: `def m = (s =~ /Branch=([^-\s]+)/ )` will get all 1 or more chars other than whitespace and hyphens into Group 1 that you can later use to instantiate a variable or write to a file, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the value after `Branch=` using:

```
String s = 'Annotations: deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1 kubernetes.io/change-cause: Branch=master-9eb8251 Message=Revert "ON-1796 Re-write the cart GET for edit cart (#1256)" (#1284) This reverts commit 27e600f83ecd98923713e2996d0aeea0da2df8fa. Author=Gautam Prajapati Timestamp=2019-07-29T16:26:32.622777'
def m = (s =~ /Branch=(\S*?)(?:-[^\s-]*)?(?!\S)/ )
if (m) {
    print(m.group(1))
}
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/co2v7G), output - `master`.

Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TByE2/4). **Details**:

- `Branch=` - literal string
- `(\S*?)` - Group 1 (the required value): any 0 or more non-whitespace chars as few as possible, but followed with
- `(?:-[^\s-]*)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and then 0+  chars other than whitespace and hyphen
- `(?!\S)` - followed with a whitespace or end of string.

Comment: If I have : Branch=master-nano-9eb8251  then this will give only master . How can I stop at last hyphen to get master-nano

Comment: @NancyChauhan Is the hyphen always there? Is yes, use `/Branch=(\S*)-/`

Comment: If not, use `Branch=(\S*?)(?:-[^\s-]*)?(?!\S)`

Comment: @NancyChauhan See the updated solution, it works with any value.

Comment: No actually indeed I used it in my code. Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, I am new to stack overflow so I messed up the likes, votes, etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to remove version tag from your branch :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher
paragraph = 'Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1                        kubernetes.io/change-cause:                          Branch=master-9eb8251 Message=Revert "ON-1796 Re-write the cart GET for edit cart (#1256)" (#1284)                          This reverts commit 27e600f83ecd98923713e2996d0aeea0da2df8fa. Author=Gautam Prajapati Timestamp=2019-07-29T16:26:32.622777'

Pattern regex = ~ /Branch=\w*/
matcher = paragraph =~ regex

println matcher[0]
```

it will stop at '-', but your branch name can have digits or '_'. depending on your needs you can use \s or other options

result is Branch=master

If your branch name contains '-', you'll have to modify some things : 
first modify the regex

```
Pattern regex = ~ /Branch=(\w*-\w*)*/
```

in the example change the branch name to Branch=master-TEST-test-9eb8251
then add some post processing on the resulting string :

```
myBranch = matcher[0][0] - matcher[0][0].split('-')[-1] // to remove the part after the last '-'
myBranch = myBranch.substring(0,myBranch.length() -1) // to remove the hyphen itself
println myBranch
```

you'll end up with Branch=master-TEST-test

Comment: Will this stop at last hyphen ? because branch can be like A-B-C-{version no} and I will require A-B-C only

Comment: this will require more processing on the regex then then on the string itself to remove the last part. I'll update my answer